# Yolov4 Training Time

Tags: tensorflow, time, deep-learning, object-detection, yolov4

Is anyone aware of **how long the training took** to achieve the mAP and FPS of **YoloV4** on the MS COCO dataset as referenced in https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet and the corresponding paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.10934.

Trying to estimate training time and final mAP for RTX 3050 without running the full training, as it is projected to take ~1500 hours.

Have not been able to find any stats for how long the training took for the Tesla V100 and RTX 2070 referenced in the paper.

Ideally could take length of time RTX 2070 took and scale according to the difference in BFLOPS, and assume accuracy is roughly similar.